# ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded production build error after upgrading from CLI 1.6.6/Angular 4.4.6 to 1.7.2/5.2.9

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I followed these steps to upgrade my project.

> **Get latest of branch to a clean folder.**
>
> Package.json (shouldn't be necessary, just confirm) Update all angular
>   versions to ^5.2.9 Update typescript to ~2.4. Update angular material
>   to ^5.2.4
>
> **In terminal npm**
>
> uninstall -g @angular/cli
>
> npm cache verify
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
>
> **In project folder**
>
> **In PowerShell** rm -r -fo node_modules
>
> **In terminal**
>     npm install -save-dev @angular/cli@latest
>
> npm install
>
> Update all rxjs calls appropriately, replace any Http references with appropriate HttpClient.

Now when I build with "ng build -e local" or "ng serve -e local" I have no problems. When I build with "ng build --prod" I get the following, supremely useful, error:

```
C:\Users\<folder>\Documents\GitHub\<projectfolder>>ng build --prod
Date: 2018-04-10T07:30:53.137Z
Hash: d8d8cd6ce7a9bbd203f1
Time: 8314ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.7995f282f7b5e2981da2.bundle.js (scripts) 170 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} styles.3ec3a6ced34b0ab98f04.bundle.css (styles) 819 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.997d8cc03812de50ae67.bundle.js (polyfills) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.ee32620ecd1edff94184.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in Invalid font values at 249:2. Ignoring.

ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

At this point I'm at a loss. I don't want to revert because of the angular animations bug in our current version which causes UI elements to remain on the screen if there is an unhandled exception (yes, I know that shouldn't be the case but .. real world). But I'm still fairly new (only about 6 months on Angular stack) and I really don't know where to begin figuring out the issue based on that error message. Before doing the upgrade, it built fine in production mode.

Any hints on debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Results of "ng -v"

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.10.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```